# 3-manifold and 2-sided projective plane.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

I would like any reference or hint on the following problem. If I have an irreducible $3$-manifold $M$ containing a 2-sided projective plane how do I know that the fundamental group of $M$ contains a $\mathbb Z/2$ subgroup? In general does the converse hold?
My really naive idea is to show that functoriality "acts well" on the definition of 2-sided and yields an injective homomorphism but I could not do it and I honestly don't see how to. Reading on Wikipedia I got more of an idea about splitting along this projective plane more in the spirit of van Kampen but I could not really write anything formal.
Thanks for any help or indication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, I am working in the smooth category (manifolds and submanifolds are smooth). Then the notion of a 2-sided surface in a 3d manifold is clear.

1. Think of the following example: $M= RP^3$, $\pi_1(M)\cong {\mathbb Z}_2$. However, $M$ is orientable, hence, cannot contain 2-sided projective planes.
   (Note that this $M$ is also irreducible.) Of course, this manifold does contain a 1-sided projective plane.
2. On the other hand, suppose that a connected 3-dimensional manifold $M$ contains a projective plane $P$. (The 2-sided condition is irrelevant.) Consider the universal covering $q: X\to M$. Then $Y=q^{-1}(P)\to P$ is a covering as well. The map $q$ restricts to covering on each component of  $Y$. Thus, each component of $Y$ is either $S^2$ or the projective plane. It is a nice exercise to check that a simply-connected 3-dimensional manifold cannot contain a projective plane (neither 2-sided, nor 1-sided), I am leaving it to you to work this out. Hence, each component of $Y$ is a 2-dimensional sphere. Take one of these components, call it $S$. Since $q(S)=P$, the projective plane, the stabilizer of $S$ in the group $G$ of covering transformations of $q$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}_2$. Thus, $G\cong \pi_1(M)$ contains ${\mathbb Z}_2$. Irreducibility of $M$ is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, so I was right about the 2-sided condition being in some way overkill? Would you consider in general any specific text to study such a topic?

Comment: @SMC: Somewhat dated is J.Hempel "3-manifolds."